# How to avoid conditionally using the same namespace in many files

Tags: c#, using-directives

I have code like the following in many files. The code is the same in every file.

```
#if SOMETHING
    using namespace1;
#else
    using namespace2;
#endif
```

However I don't want to have to maintain these same five lines in many files.

Ideally I would like to do something like this in a separate file:

```
#if SOMETHING
    var namespace = namespace1;
#else
    var namespace = namespace2;
#endif
```

And then in all the other files:

```
using namespace
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: You are looking for Dependency Injection

Comment: why do you even have 2 namespaces there ? .... there is a problem there i believe

Comment: I'm actually interested in whether my suggested solution is possible and will mark the answers accordingly

Comment: @cja: No, not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid having the same code in different namespaces twice to start with.

Just generate the code *once*, but then wherever you create an instance of the web service, specify the URL you want to connect to. (You probably want to centralize that code, mind you.)

Look at the properties in the web service - I'm sure one of them will be the base URL. Just because it defaults to one particular URL (ideally something invalid, so that you never end up making accidental calls to the wrong environment due to not setting it) doesn't mean you can't change it programmatically at execution time.

Comment: Can I do it the way I'm suggesting?

Comment: @cja: Well you could have that in *one* file that acts as a proxy - but why would you *want* to do it that way? It's just not the right solution, IMO. Why would you want to run *different code* just to talk to a test environment? Think about what you'd do for different databases - you wouldn't have `SqlConnectionProd` and `SqlConnectionTest` - you'd just have `SqlConnection` and pass in different connection strings. It's the same for web services.

Comment: "you could have that in one file that acts as a proxy" - excellent, please can you give an example? I can't work out how to do it, hence my original question.

Comment: @cja: It would have to look just like the rest of the code in terms of API, but delegate to the existing one. So it would be a *third* copy of that API. I really *very strongly* urge you not to do this, to the extent that I don't want to provide sample code, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hang on, are you talking about a namespace proxy or a web reference proxy? All I'm asking about is a way to have a variable that keeps a reference to one namespace or another and then to reference that variable in a using statement. (Or something to that effect.) The web services are really nothing to do with my question and I shouldn't have mentioned them.

Comment: @cja: I was talking about an extra class which would conditionally pull in one or the other, and delegate all calls. If this isn't about web services, you should use a different example in the question - because any time you've got the same code in two different namespaces, that's a smell.

Comment: I have rewritten my question to remove all evidence of my scenario to make it clearer what I am asking.

Comment: @cja: Well now it's even *more* of an XY problem. Basically, you can't do this - if you give more context, we can explain a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You're going about it the wrong way. Don't have 2 references, just have one to the test service and then in the production build of your application, change the URL in the app/web config to point to the production URL.

Comment: Can I do it the way I'm suggesting?

Comment: @cja, why would you want to?  You're creating an issue for something where there are already standard solutions (urls in configs typically) and probably adding future maintenance issues especially if someone new needs to work on the code base.